# Random Error connection to mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I have a application in asp.net with mySQL database. 
When many clients are using the application on the same time there begins to come mysql errors:

```
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on (myip)
```

The error always occor in lines like:

```
conn.open()` OR `cmd.fill(ds,"mytable")
```

I have checked the numbers of connection with the tool Jet Profiler and the numbers of open connection doesnt exceed the allowed number.
In the Jet Profiler tool seems everything OK when the error occur.

I am using connection pool

What could cause this random error?

Comment: check whether you close all the connections after you use them. try to do it in `finally` block to make sure connection close.

Comment: are your connections persistent?

Comment: Thank you for replying.
All my connections are closed. 
I dont really know if my connections are persistent. I have a server manager to take care of my server and I can ask him.
Is it better with persistent connections?